# Purpose of parallel arrows in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

What is purpose of parallel arrows in category theory? Is there a simple example demonstrating how they work and why it is advantageous to allow two (and presumably more than two) arrows, as opposed to just one?

Comment: Personally, I like having more than one function between sets, or more than one homomorphism between rings, etc.

Comment: Where did you see such "parallel arrows"? This will probably give you an answer to your question. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_(mathematics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People have been working with specific examples of categories since long before the modern definition of a “category” came to be.
Some examples are what we would nowadays call the categories of

- topological spaces,
- groups,
- sets,
- rings,
- smooth manifolds,
- Lie groups,
- Lie algebras,
- …

In all of these examples there are parallel arrows.
More generally, in basically every kind of category that people care about there are parallel morphisms.
And not just a few of them, but typically *a lot* of parallel morphisms.
(There is exactly one kind of category that doesn’t have parallel arrows, namely preordered sets.)

The abstract definition of a category exists to model the examples that people care about.
Therefore, we must allow parallel arrows.

We could, theoretically, redefine “category” so that parallel arrows are not allowed.
But virtually no one would use this redefinition, since it doesn’t apply to the examples that people care about.